# jQuery’s event.stopImmediatePropagation() only prevents events bound afterwards?

Tags: jquery, propagation

I was under the impression that `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` stopped all other bound event handlers, but on my current code it only seems to stop events bound *after* my function that calls `stopImmediatePropagation`. Is this correct, and if so how can I get the result I want without unbinding and rebinding all over the place?

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent the handlers that *already have executed before your own* from executing?

Comment: It is working correctly as handlers are executed in the order that they are bound. So you either need to ensure that you handler that calls stopImmediatePropagation is bound first or find some other way (not overly helpful, sorry).

Comment: OK, understood :) Any way of shuffling around bound event orders? Or I guess I could delegate the secondary event instead of binding and prevent propagation from there? Experimentation time I think. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by [Richard Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338208/richard-dalton) by pointing out that I was misunderstanding how the system worked.

> It is working correctly as handlers are executed in the order that they are bound. So you either need to ensure that you handler that calls `stopImmediatePropagation` is bound first or find some other way.